# Showing that a function is continuous on a topological manifold.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, manifolds

Given a d-dimensional topological manifold $(M,\mathcal{O}_M,\mathcal{A})$, here $M$ is the set, $\mathcal{O}_M$ the topology on $M$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the associated atlas. Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}\to M$ be some path.

Now the atlas $\mathcal{A}$ is just a collection of charts (I index the charts by $\alpha$) $(x_\alpha,U_\alpha)$, i.e $x:U_\alpha\to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $U_\alpha\subset M$. Then I heard that continuity of the path $\rho$ depends on the continuity of all the chart maps $x_\alpha$ since $\rho=x^{-1}\circ x \circ \rho$ and the composition of continuous maps is continuous.

However I am having a little trouble making this rigorous. Please help finish this argument : for continuity consider a set $B\in \mathcal{O}_M$, I need to check that $\rho^{-1}(B)$ is in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (of course this is the standard topology). How can I rigorously relate the set $B$ to the charts $U_\alpha$...?

EDIT: To clarify I want to to show that  if for all chart maps $x_\alpha \circ \rho$ is continuous then this implies $\rho$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you assuming $\rho$ is continuous?  If so, then $\rho^{-1}(B)$ is open by definition of continuous.  And, you can write $B = \bigcup_{\alpha} (B\cap U_\alpha)$, which *may* be helpful.

Comment: @JasonDeVito no I want to show that if for all chart maps $x_\alpha \circ \rho$ is continuous then this implies $\rho$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for every chart $(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)$, that $ x_\alpha \circ \rho:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is continuous.  We need to show that $\rho$ is continuos.

So, suppose $B\subseteq M$ is open.  We need show that $\rho^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Here is a sequence of hints which will lead to this answer.

1. Show that $B = \bigcup_{\alpha}(B\cap U_\alpha)$.
2. Show that $\rho^{-1}(B) = \bigcup_{\alpha} \rho^{-1}(B\cap U_\alpha)$.

So, if we can show that each $\rho^{-1}(B\cap U_\alpha)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\rho^{-1}(B)$ will be written as a union of open sets, so will be open.  Thus, we need only show that $\rho^{-1}(B\cap U_{\alpha})$ is open for every $\alpha$.

3. Fixing a particular chart $(U,x)$, show that $x(B\cap U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
4. Show that $(x\circ \rho)^{-1}(x(B\cap U))$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
5. Show that $(x\circ\rho)^{-1}(x(B\cap U)) = \rho^{-1}(B\cap U)$ and conclude the proof.

Comment: I'm happy to add details/hints if needed.

Comment: I guess it is an if and only if statement too

Comment: Jason, in your opinion, what is the most accessible book to learn some of these basic results of Riemannian Geometry ?

Comment: Yes, it's an if and only if statement, but the other direction is easier.  I learned all this stuff from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book.